# Publish WCF service to Azure without adding code to source control?

Tags: c#, azure, wcf, visual-studio-2017

I create a WCF service in VS2017 and decided to publish it in Azure to see how it goes. Azure has a $200 credit, so I decided to try it out.

When I try to publish it, Visual Studio tells me that I have to add the code to a remote source control before publishing the service to Azure. I cannot do that because our client wants to keep all the source code in the company's servers.

We just need Azure so that I can publish the service so it's accessible to the outside.

Is copying our source code to a remote repository a requirement for publishing a WCF service in Azure?

Answer (score 0):

It is **`not`** mandatory to have your code inside Azure in order to deploy it directly from Visual Studio 2019.

however if you are planning to have CI/CD you need to have the source code provided from either one of the following sources such as Git or Azure Devops

[image]

Comment: Thanks. What is `CI/CD`? Also, it's Visual Studio 2017, not 2019. Does it make a difference?

Comment: CI/CD stands for Continous Integration and Continous Deployment with Azure devops. VS2017 and 2019 does not make any difference. So the answer remains the same

Comment: To summarize, I am required to copy my WCF source code to an external repository before publishing the WCF to Azure?

Comment: Simple answer is Yes. For any software that you write you need to have a source control where your source code resides. It's the same with Azure devops as well. Recommended practices is to have it on Azure as you already have a subscription. But you could have it on onprem/github/svn etc . choice is yours

Comment: The WCF code is already under source control on our server. I just need Azure to host the service. The client doesn't want to copy their code to an external repository.

Comment: Alright in that case you need to look at azure devops. and see the source where you can pick source as yours https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/index?view=azure-devops

Comment: did the answer help you